# Angular2 Component communication in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to communicate between two component in Angular 2 using JS. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjUCEnlc0PI) is link for tutorial.
I think I am missing something with directives. 
I tried to change it with declarations as well

This is app.main.js

```
(function () {

var Component = ng.core.Component
var bootstrap = ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap

var RandomComponent = Component({
    selector: 'random-component',
    template: `
        <h2> Hsdsdffdsdfi <h2>
        `
}).Class({
    constructor: function() {
        //empty
    }
});

var AppComponent = Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    directives: [RandomComponent],
    template: `
        <h1> Hi {{username}}<h1>
        <random-component></random-component>
        `
}).Class({
    constructor: function() {
        //empty
        this.username = "Username"
    }
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    bootstrap(AppComponent);
});
```

})();

and this is index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart JS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfill -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
    <script src='app/app.main.js'></script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <main-app>Loading....</main-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am currently using Angular 2 RC5, and do not wish to go to ts. I also could not find any documentation regarding JS as well. If anyone knows a good documentation link for 'JS' (not ts), please help with that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NgModules

Angular2 RC5 introduced NgModules. According to the documentation,

> Angular Modules help organize an application into cohesive blocks of functionality.

You need to define at least one module in your Angular application. You also should bootstrap that (root/main) module instead of a component (AppComponent in your case).

Another change is the way you declare your components and directives. Instead of using the ***directives*** property in every component, now you list them in the module using the **declarations** property.

Here's the working solution:

```
(function () {
    var Component = ng.core.Component
    var NgModule = ng.core.NgModule;
    var BrowserModule = ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule;
    var bootstrap = ng.platformBrowserDynamic;

    var AppComponent = Component({
        selector: 'main-app',
        template: `
            <h1>Hi {{username}}</h1>
            <random-component></random-component>
            `
    }).Class({
        constructor: function() {
            this.username = 'Username';
        }
    });

    var RandomComponent = Component({
        selector: 'random-component',
        template: `
            <h2>Random title<h2>
            `
    }).Class({
        constructor: function() { }
    });

    AppModule = NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            RandomComponent,
            AppComponent
        ],
        bootstrap: [
            AppComponent
        ]})
        .Class({
            constructor: function() { }
        });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        bootstrap.platformBrowserDynamic()
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    });
})();
```

## Tutorials

Unfortunately, the Angular 2.0 docs about Javascript are definitely not as rich as the docs about Typescript. You can check the [QuickStart Guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) (there's and appendix regarding NgModule) or the corresponding [Typescript chapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html).

Comment: Can you please link the docs? Are [these](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/) the docs? Maybe I missed something. I already worked on quick start and typescript chapter. Thanks btw.

Comment: Yup, these are the official docs, but as you can see there are a lot JavaScript (and in fact Dart) chapters missing.